# Expecting EDGE_TYPE or ID. Microsoft SQL Server MS

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, here's the code in which I'm asking for help with the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '('. Expecting EDGE_TYPE or ID.

The following database is a project for UNI, in which i need to create a car/owner database.
Can the same model I used in /* CERINTA 4 */ be used for /* CERINTA 5 */ where the error occurs?

```
CREATE DATABASE munteanu_db_prob3;

/*CERINTA 1*/
/*IMPLEMENTARE BAZA DATE*/
CREATE TABLE vehicul(NR_VEHICUL INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, MARCA VARCHAR(12), TIP VARCHAR(12), SERIE VARCHAR(16), CULOARE VARCHAR(12), CAPACITATE_CIL INT, PRIMARY KEY(NR_VEHICUL));
CREATE TABLE persoana(NR_PERSOANA INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, SERIE_BUL VARCHAR(2), NR_BUL VARCHAR(6), ADRESA VARCHAR(20), PRIMARY KEY(NR_PERSOANA));
CREATE TABLE proprietate(ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, PERSOANA_ID INT,  NR_VEHICUL INT, DATA_CUMPARARII DATETIME default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, PRET FLOAT, PRIMARY KEY(ID),
                     FOREIGN KEY(NR_VEHICUL) REFERENCES vehicul(NR_VEHICUL), FOREIGN KEY(PERSOANA_ID) REFERENCES persoana(NR_PERSOANA));

/*INSTANTIERE BAZA DATE*/
INSERT INTO vehicul(MARCA, TIP,SERIE,CULOARE,CAPACITATE_CIL)
        VALUES ('VOLKSWAGEN', 'HATCHBACK', '3333333333333x00', 'VISINIU', 1967),
               ('AUDI', 'HATCHBACK', '3333333333333x01', 'GRI', 1967),
               ('BMW', 'HOTHATCH', '3333333333333x02', 'NEGRU', 2180),
               ('OPEL', 'COUPE', '3333333333333x03', 'NEGRU', 1669), 
               ('FORD', 'BREAK', '3333333333333x04', 'ALB', 1556),
               ('SUZUKI','CROSSOVER', '3333333333333x05','ALB', 1578),
               ('DACIA', 'SEDAN', '3333333333333x06','ALBASTRU', 1396),
               ('MERCEDES','SEDAN', '3333333333333x07', 'NEGRU', 2167);

INSERT INTO persoana(SERIE_BUL, NR_BUL, ADRESA)
        VALUES ('DX', '432514', 'Strada Dreptatii NR 01'), 
               ('DZ', '532435', 'Strada Academiei NR 02'),
               ('BZ', '634344', 'Strada Romania Muncitoare NR 03'),
               ('BV', '123475', 'Strada Muntilor NR 99'),
               ('DX', '352443', 'Bulevardul Dezrobirii NR 01');

INSERT INTO proprietate(PERSOANA_ID, NR_VEHICUL, PRET)
        VALUES (1, 1, 10.000),
               (2, 4, 25.000),
               (3, 5, 125.000),
               (5, 2, 14.000),
               (1, 7, 90.000),
               (4,1,15.000),
               (1,6, 4.000);

/*CERINTA 2*/
/*DET. NUMARUL DE CULORI*/
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CULOARE) FROM vehicul;

/*DET. NUMARUL DE MASINI DE FIECARE CULOARE*/
SELECT CULOARE, COUNT(CULOARE) FROM vehicul GROUP BY CULOARE;


/*CERINTA 3*/
/*DET. MARCI MASINI*/
SELECT DISTINCT MARCA FROM vehicul;

/*DET. NR. VEHICULE DE FIECARE MARCA*/
SELECT MARCA, COUNT(MARCA) FROM vehicul GROUP BY MARCA;


/*CERINTA 4*/
/*PROCEDURA CALCUL NR. MASINI*/
/*PROCEDURA CALCUL PRET MEDIU MASINI CULOARE NEAGRA*/
/*(AVERAGE)pret de culoare*/
SELECT COUNT(vehicul.NR_VEHICUL), AVG(proprietate.PRET)
   FROM vehicul, proprietate
        WHERE vehicul.NR_VEHICUL = proprietate.NR_VEHICUL and culoare='Negru'
              GROUP BY vehicul.CULOARE;


/*CERINTA 5*/
CREATE TABLE prop2veh AS(SELECT proprietate.PERSOANA_ID, proprietate.NR_VEHICUL
                  FROM proprietate
                  INNER JOIN vehicul ON proprietate.NR_VEHICUL=vehicul.NR_VEHICUL);


SELECT PERSOANA_ID, Count(*) As total FROM prop2veh Group By PERSOANA_ID Having Count(*) > 2
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense here. "CERINTA 5" is incredibly confusing. A table is not a select statement. And you really should get in the habit of using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Maybe you are attempting to use proper join syntax? Maybe that could be a view instead of a table? I just don't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @SeanLange, here's the short-story, I'm a newbie in sql, yet I have to create a database that holds a cars(masini) table, with its brand, chassis type, VIN, color and engine displacement.(in order from the first create table), owner(proprietar) with it's info and property(proprietate).
At "CERINTA 5" I need to determine the owners with more than 2 cars.

Comment: So what is wrong with the query you wrote at the end?  That seems to work.

Comment: After some google searches, the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio doesn't 'know'/'have' the "CREATE TABLE ... AS(SELECT...) (which by the way was written by a colleague of mine as I asked for help). The only thing I found was to try and use a similar code from 'CERINTA 4' with "SELECT COUNT(proprietate.NR_VEHICUL...) but I don't know how to formulate the entire line of code.

Comment: A table can't be a select statement. It makes no sense. A table is a repository for storing data. A select statement is used to retrieve stored data. The query at the end you have seems to be fine. Get rid of that create table prop2ven nonsense.

Comment: Fully understand that a table can't be a select statement. Yet I think I need a select statement to retrieve which one of the owners own 2 or more cars.
And as I understand the "prop2ven" CREATE TABLE is used to create a table that stores the NR_VEHICUL and PERSOANA_ID from proprietate(property) and JOIN it with the vehicul(vehicle) table in order to group the owners which own 2 or more cars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are way overthinking this. Your query would be as simple as this.

```
SELECT p.PERSOANA_ID
    , MyCount = count(*)
FROM proprietate p 
INNER JOIN vehicul v ON p.NR_VEHICUL = v.NR_VEHICUL
group by p.PERSOANA_ID
hacing count(*) > 2
```

Comment: It worked, at first glance. Thank you so much for your support. I'll keep the post updated if I encounter any more problems. Thank you so much, kudos!

Answer (score 0):

`CREATE TABLE prop2veh  AS (SELECT...` is not proper TSQL syntax.

The proper way is `SELECT {column list} INTO prop2veh FROM {Table(s)}`

Comment: Can you be more explicit about the SELECT ... INTO prop2veh syntax, I don't know to write it all

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?ei=A18NW-OFL4XetQW_p5DIDQ&q=sql+server+select+into+example&oq=sql+server+select+into+example&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30k1l9.2664.3536.0.4281.8.8.0.0.0.0.171.762.0j6.6.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..2.6.761...35i39k1.0.JaIGYVzG8co

Comment: While Tab is absolutely correct about the syntax I would not use this here. If a user sells a car your data would be stale. This should be a view instead of a persistent table.

Comment: This is what I was searching for at first, aparently @SeanLange fixed it already. Thank you also.